# jQuery - Toggle grid on draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Let's say I have a grid and create it using it like so:

```
$( "#dragIt" ).draggable({ grid: [ 15, 15 ] });
```

Then, I have a checkbox below the `div`. Is there anyway when I toggle the checkbox, that the grid becomes on and off? I can't find it [official jquery ui website](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to) on how to turn it off/on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://jsbin.com/ewamuq/1/edit

```
$(function () {
  $("#draggable4").draggable({
    grid: [15, 15]
  });

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    if ($(':checked').length > 0) {
      $("#draggable4").draggable({
        grid: false
      });
    } else {
      $("#draggable4").draggable({
        grid: [15, 15]
      });
    }
  });
});
```